# How to programmatically change the button foreground color in Xcode?

Tags: xcode13

I have a button with a system image and no Title string. I want to programmatically change the foreground color of the system image. I tried

myBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.systemYellow, for: .normal)

This doesn't work. I know I can change the foreground color using the Interactive Builder. In the button's Attribute Inspector, there's a Foreground field that allows me to change the foreground color, but I can't find the method that accesses that attribute.

[Attribute Inspector Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19apG.png)

Regards,
Tim

Answer (score 3):

You may need to use the [UIButton.Configuration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/configuration/) API introduced in iOS 15. Setting the foreground color in the storyboard would set the `baseForegroundColor` of the configuration, rather than calling `setTitleColor(_:for:)`.

So set the button foreground color with:

```
myBtn.configuration?.baseForegroundColor = UIColor.systemYellow
```